# Check image dimensions (height and width) before uploading image using PHP

Tags: php, image, file-upload, dimensions

How can I check for height and width before uploading image, using PHP.

Must I upload the image first and use "getimagesize()"? Or can I check this before uploading it using PHP?

```
<?php

foreach ($_FILES["files"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
if(
$error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK
&& $_FILES["files"]["size"][$key] < 500000 
&& $_FILES["files"]["type"][$key] == "image/gif"
|| $_FILES["files"]["type"][$key] == "image/png"
|| $_FILES["files"]["type"][$key] == "image/jpeg"
|| $_FILES["files"]["type"][$key] == "image/pjpeg" 
){


$filename = $_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];








if(HOW TO CHECK WIDTH AND HEIGHT)
{
echo '<p>image dimenssions must be less than 1000px width and 1000px height';
}


}







?>
```

Comment: You cannot check a file using PHP that is not uploaded to the server. If it has to be PHP, it's not possible.

Comment: Guess I have to upload it then, and "unlik" it if it exceed 1000px :) Or use JavaScript if I can make it an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something that is executed on the client before the actual upload happens.
With (server-side) php you can check the dimension only after the file has been uploaded or with [upload hooks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-v525/) *maybe* while the image is uploaded (from the image file header data).

So your options are flash, maybe html5 with its FileAPI (haven't tested that, maybe that's not doable), java-applet, silverlight, ...

Answer (score 111):

We can do this with temp file easily.

```
$image_info = getimagesize($_FILES["file_field_name"]["tmp_name"]);
$image_width = $image_info[0];
$image_height = $image_info[1];
```

Comment: Works perfect! I have tested it myself, and the image size is displayed perfectly.

Answer (score 10):

This is how I solved it.

```
$test = getimagesize('../bilder/' . $filnamn);
$width = $test[0];
$height = $test[1];

if ($width > 1000 || $height > 1000)
{
echo '<p>iamge is to big';
unlink('../bilder/'.$filnamn);
}
```

Comment: Why check after image is already uploaded? & then spending time to unlink again

Answer (score 6):

If the file is in the `$_FILES` array (because it's been selected in a Multipart form), it has already been uploaded to the server (usually to /tmp or similar file path) so you can just go ahead and use the `getimagesize()` function in php to get the dimensions (including all details as array).

Answer (score 6):

This work for me

```
$file = $_FILES["files"]['tmp_name'];
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);

if($width > "180" || $height > "70") {
    echo "Error : image size must be 180 x 70 pixels.";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: As a good practice you should also explain your answer a bit as it helps the understanding

Answer (score 5):

To get the width and height of the image use `getimagesize(path_name)`, this function returns the array which contains the height, width, image_type constant and other image related info. By the following code you can achive that.

**Note** - 
Need to pass temporary location of the image, and use the following piece of code before you use `move_upload_file()`, else it will move the file to destination path and you wont get the desired result for the image

```
$imageInformation = getimagesize($_FILES['celebrity_pic']['tmp_name']);
print_r($imageInformation);

$imageWidth = $imageInformation[0]; //Contains the Width of the Image

$imageHeight = $imageInformation[1]; //Contains the Height of the Image

if($imageWidth >= your_value && $imageHeight >= your_value)
{
  //Your Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 array getimagesize ( string $filename [, array &$imageinfo ] )
```

The getimagesize() function will determine the size of any given image file and return the dimensions along with the file type and a height/width text string to be used inside a normal HTML IMG tag and the correspondant HTTP content type.

For more update visit site:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Answer (score 0):

Very important -  if you are using Dreamweaver to code and you try to get the image size using the `$_FILES[anyFormName][tmp_name]` it will display an error in live view.. It took me a while to figure this out.

Comment: did you set your form as "multipart/form-data"?