# About image upload validation in HTML5 or Javascript or jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

Is there is any method for validating the dimensions of the image file before uploading to the server ..

In details

I had a PHP file upload form and image upload will restrict with specific dimensions . Already I am checking in server side and also I wanna check the image dimensions before uploading process

Please help 
Thanks

Comment: I've only seen it done with flash / silverlight / exe / applet, never seen it with pure html yet, similar question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486414/check-image-dimensions-height-and-width-before-uploading-image-using-php

Comment: until it is uploaded  php has nothing to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. [pupload](http://www.plupload.com/) for example can resize images on the client side.

Take a look at the [HTML5 runtime source](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/src/javascript/plupload.html5.js#L48) to see how it determines the dimensions.

Comment: PLupload rocks! +1, Side note: "Image resizing is only possible on Firefox 3.5+ (with fixed quality) acnd Chrome. Safari/Opera doesn't support direct data access to the selected files." - http://www.plupload.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/WQNzY/1/ I've created based on this great [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications)

It make use of FileReader API, so you would like to check what [browsers support](http://caniuse.com/#search=FileReader) it currently. Now it works in Mozilla, Chrome, Opera. But sure for old browsers you need anyway use server side validation. Not a big deal because you anyway need it alongside with client-side but for modern browsers you could make user experience more smooth and pleasent.