# Firefox .naturalHeight property

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have the following code:

```
 var checkImgDim=new Image();
 checkImgDim.src=e.target.result;

 if (input.files[0].size > MAX_SIZE) 
    setError("File too large - max 3MB");

 else if (checkImgDim.naturalHeight < MIN_H ||
          checkImgDim.naturalWidth < MIN_W)
    setError("Image dimensions too small");
```

It works fine under Chrome however with Firefox I'm getting inconsistent results because it seems that naturalHeight and naturalWidth return 0 sometimes and there's a delay before the values are set. I don't want to load the image into the DOM or use .onload() the whole purpose of the code is simply to check the image dimensions. I don't think it would be good  practice to add a time delay here. Can someone please tell me what the proper way to check the image dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get image size before it is loaded. You should use the `load` event of the image anyway. Even if the image URL is actually a Data URI (e. g. if it comes from a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)), it is “loaded” into the image object *asynchronously*.

It’s not necessary to insert the image as an HTML element into DOM for this. Just create a new `Image` object, add a `load` listener to it, and then set its `src` property.

```
var image = new Image;

image.onload = function() {
    alert(this.naturalHeight);
};

image.src = 'example.png';
```

If the image has already been downloaded before, it will not be downloaded again — its cached copy will be used instead (as long as client-side caching itself is not disabled intentionally via corresponding server-response headers). If the image URL is actually a Data URI, there is no downloading at all.

Note that `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` properties are relatively new and some browsers may not support them. So using regular `width` and `height` properties is currently more reliable, and they have the same values as long as their values have not been changed explicitly before.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED WITHOUT ONLOAD:

I think you can get the image dimensions before it's loaded by using a 0 second interval - it will technically return the dimensions before onload is called but this solution does use a delay like you said you wanted to avoid however I cannot think of another way of doing it. This way is at least quicker than onload.

```
var loaded = false;
var checkImgDim = new Image();

checkImgDim.onload = function () { loaded = true; };

var wait = setInterval(function () {
    if (loaded) {
        clearInterval(wait);
    } else {
        console.log(checkImgDim.naturalWidth, checkImgDim.naturalHeight);
    }
}, 0);
```

Comment: Hi Thom, doesn't .onload() wait until it's loaded into the DOM?

Comment: I want to check the naturalHeight and width without loading the image into the DOM...

Comment: My mistake I completely missed out the part where you said you didn't want to use onload! Editing now...

Comment: Thanks Thom, if there's no easy way of doing this i'll have to do it on the server side instead.

Comment: Sorry Xenophon, I think I would personally stick to doing it server side. Especially PHP it's a lot easier (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13393813/6479294)

Comment: Here you're just over-complicating the code and is moving the async part out the the handler, i.e. pretty pointless. Marat's approach is the correct one. You cannot get orange juice from a ketchup-bottle..

Comment: @K3N if you check the edit history I gave the exact code that Marat gave, however Xenophon specifically said he didn't want to use onload so I came up with this solution instead to show that it isn't easily possible without onload, and is actually pretty 'hacky'